# Room cannot verify data integrity but I have desctructive migration enabled

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm getting an error from `Room` `IllegalStateException` with the trace that "Room cannot verify data integrity" as I changed a db value from non nullable to nullable, but my db setup is as follows:

```
@JvmStatic
@Provides
@ApplicationScope
fun provideRoomDatabase(context: Application): MyDb = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context,
    MyDb::class.java, DB_NAME
).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
```

What could be a problem with this?

Comment: have you increased the database version after making the change?

Comment: do I have to? Since `fallingBackToDestructiveMigration()` recreates db for me?

Comment: It does, but as mentioned in doc https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions sometimes it still uses the old schema, so by increasing the version, you can fix your exception

Comment: you can answer this and confirm and close. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you increased the database version after making the change? Since it does recreates the database but sometimes it still uses the old schema, so by increasing the version, you can fix your exception. You can check it in the docs here as well [Room Migration](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions)

> After updating your database's schemas, it's possible that some on-device databases could still use an older schema version. If Room cannot find a migration rule for upgrading that device's database from the older version to the current version, an IllegalStateException occurs.